# Proving the definition of $\arcsin x$ using analysis

Tags: real-analysis, integration, trigonometry

My goal is to prove that the function $\arcsin:\left [ -1,1 \right ]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ can be defined as 
$$x \mapsto \arcsin x \equiv \int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} \ dt,$$
which is odd and continuous.  Assume nothing about the sine function is known.

Showing the function is continuous on $(-1,1)$ just follows from the definition.

Showing the function is odd should be as simple as showing that 
$$f(-x)=-f(x).$$
Plugging this in gives 
$$f(-x)=\int_{0}^{-x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} \ dt=-\int_{-x}^{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} \ dt.$$
I am not too sure what to do next.

Lastly, I think the bulk of the question is to prove that the function we are integrating is Riemann integrable.  That is, it is a valid definition.  I am having trouble on this part as well because I am not sure how to construct my partition $P$ such that 
$$U(f;P)-L(f;P)<\epsilon.$$
I know this a lot- I am pretty confused!  Can anyone provide me some feedback and help?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: continuous functions are Riemann integrable.

Comment: How would one construct the epsilon-delta continuity proof for that function, though?

Comment: Are you just trying to prove that $f(x) = \int_0^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\text dt$ is a continuous odd function on the interval $[-1,1]$?

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 Yes.  The question is worded weirdly but that is what it comes down to.  I am a little stuck.

Comment: You are on the right track, just let $t \to -t$ in the last integral and simplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powers and sums are continuous, and compositions of continuous functions are continuous, so the integrand is continuous on $(-1,1)$ hence RI, by the FTC, $\sin^{-1}(x)$ is continuous. For oddness, use the change of variables $u=-x$.

Assume $x\ge 1/2$. Because the integrand is positive, the integral increases in $x$, so the change of variables $u=1-t^2$ expresses value of $|\arcsin 1-\arcsin x| $ as
$$ \int_x^1 \frac {\text{d}u}{2\sqrt u \sqrt{1-u}}\le \frac 1{\sqrt 2}\int_{x}^1\frac {\text{d}u}{\sqrt{1-u}}=\sqrt 2\sqrt{1-x}\to 0 \quad \text{as $x\to 1$}$$
Thus, $\arcsin x$ is continuous at $1$. The same procedure can be applied at $-1$.

Comment: This is good for the open interval $(-1,1)$. However, you need to show the endpoints separately. Consider $g(x) = \frac{1}{1-|x|}$ continuous on $(-1,1)$ but $\int_0^x g(t)\text dt$ not defined for $x \in \{-1,1\}$.

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 Edited my post.

Comment: Another approach to deal with endpoints of $[-1,1]$ is to note the equality $$\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{1-t^2}\,dt=\frac{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$$ valid for $x\in(-1,1)$. Taking limits as $x\to \pm 1$ shows that the integral in question converges if $x=\pm 1$.